# JS date format gives -1 day

Tags: javascript, date

I want to format my date with toIsoString function but the function returns -1 day how to fix it? the event.value format is `Tue Apr 19 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0400 (Armenia Standard Time)`

```
 console.log(new Date(event.value).toISOString().slice(0,10))
```

in the console, I'm getting this one `2022-04-18` how you can see the result was -1 day

```
  startDateChange(event: any): void{
    this.firstDayOfMonth = event;
    console.log(new Date(event.value).toISOString().slice(0, 10));
  }
```

Comment: You need to add the function here as well to check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of your timezone settings. The `toISOString` is always returning `+0000` while you work with `+0400` in your timezone. This essentially withdraws 4 hours resulting in the day before, 20:00 hours.

You could try to fix this by setting the timezone offset to 0 by adding a Z to the date as shown in the second example.

The third example is a safe way to do it but you need to prefix the 0 if you need that.

Another alternative would be to use a date-library like Moment.js, although moment is deprecated (I don't know for sure what the best alternative would be, that's up to you).

```js
// Your example (this might work for some people that are in the +0000 timezone)
console.log(new Date('2021-03-03T00:00:00').toISOString().slice(0,10));

// Second example
console.log(new Date('2021-03-03T00:00:00z').toISOString().slice(0,10));

// Third example
const date = new Date('2021-03-03T00:00:00');
const year = date.getFullYear();
const month = date.getMonth() + 1;
const day = date.getDate();

console.log(`${year}-${month}-${day}`);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://day.js.org/

Code:

```js
const dateString = 'Tue Apr 19 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0400 (Armenia Standard Time)'

const date1 = dayjs(dateString).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
console.log(date1)

const date2 = dayjs(dateString).format('YYYY-M-D')
console.log(date2)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dayjs/1.11.0/dayjs.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I solved the issue by using the timezone plugin from Dayjs. If you use `dayjs`, it's because of the timezone. I solved this with this line.

```
import * as dayjs from 'dayjs';
import * as timezone from 'dayjs/plugin/timezone';
import * as utc from 'dayjs/plugin/utc';
import * as customParseFormat from 'dayjs/plugin/customParseFormat';

dayjs.extend(customParseFormat);
dayjs.extend(utc);
dayjs.extend(timezone);

reviewData.dateComplete = "20-02-2024"
const dateTz = dayjs.tz(reviewData.dateComplete, 'DD-MM-YYYY','UTC').toDate();
console.log(dateTz) // 2024-02-20T00:00:00.000Z
```