# Importing date without local time transformation

Tags: node.js, date, timezone, dayjs

I am getting a date in DD-MMM-YY format, and am using dayjs to convert it to standard date format in nodejs.
However, the returned date is 1 day earlier than the input date.
I was told this is probably due to some difference in the server local time.
I can easily just add a day to the date, but as this will be a global function that works in multiple time zones, I just want to get the date "as is" without any automatic adjustments.
This is my function:

```
const convertDate = (date,format,zone) => {
  dayjs.tz.setDefault(zone);
  console.log(date);
  console.log(dayjs(date));
  console.log(dayjs.utc(date).$d);
  console.log(dayjs.tz(date,format,zone).$d);
  var newDate = dayjs.tz(date,zone);
  //newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate());
  return newDate;
}
```

No matter which methods I use or which zone I set, the date comes out as one day earlier than the input date.
For example, for a date of 01-APR-03 I get:
2003-03-31T21:00:00.000Z

I want the time to just be 2003-04-01T00:00:00.000Z.

Following comments, I have tried the following approach, but the result is the same:

```
const fixMonthName = (s) => s.replace(/[A-Z]{2}-/, (m) => m.toLowerCase());
  const d = dayjs.utc(fixMonthName("22-FEB-02"), "DD-MMM-YY");
  console.log(d);
  const s = d.toISOString();
console.log(s); //{result:
M {
  '$L': 'en',
  '$u': true,
  '$d': 2002-02-21T22:00:00.000Z,
  '$x': {},
  '$y': 2002,
  '$M': 1,
  '$D': 21,
  '$W': 4,
  '$H': 22,
  '$m': 0,
  '$s': 0,
  '$ms': 0
}}
2002-02-21T22:00:00.000Z
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JS date format gives -1 day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71704131/js-date-format-gives-1-day)

Answer (score 2):

Let's recap the problem:

- You have a date-only string value of `01-APR-03` (equivalent to `2003-04-01`).
- You're then parsing it as timestamp, treating it as if it were `2003-04-01T00:00:00.000` (local time).  This is the cause of the logical error.
- Then you're looking at a UTC representation (`2003-03-31T21:00:00.000Z` in your example), and wondering why it's been shifted.  (`Z` means UTC)

Fundamentally, a date and a timestamp are two different concepts.  If you conflate them, you will have complications in your code such as the one you described.

- A date can be thought of as a half-open *range* of timestamps (from the start of one day, to just before the start of the next).  In other words, logically the following is true:

  ```
  '2003-04-01' == ['2003-04-01T00:00:00.000', '2003-04-02T00:00:00.000')
  ```

If you parse a date-only value to an object that represents a timestamp, you are choosing to assign a point-in-time within that range. Thus, if you pick the very start of the range, you can easily shift into a different day when viewing that from another time zone.

**Note that the JavaScript `Date` object is misnamed.  It isn't a *date*, it's a *timestamp*.**

- A `day.js` object also represents a *timestamp*, as do most other libraries including Moment, Luxon, date-fns, and many others.

There are a few different solutions to this problem:

- You can pick a time in the middle of the range which is less likely to be shifted to a different date when viewed from another time zone.  For example, `12:00:00` noon.  (Though this isn't perfect, as there are some time zones that go up to UTC+14.)
- You can *avoid* treating a date as a timestamp, by keeping it in an object or string that represents it as a whole date.

  - Unfortunately, this isn't a concept that has caught on well in JavaScript yet.  The language and most libraries do not handle it this way.  (One notable exception is [js-joda](https://js-joda.github.io/js-joda/), which has a `LocalDate` data type.)  However, this will eventually be coming to the JavaScript language itself via the [Temporal proposal](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/), which adds `Temporal.PlainDate`.
- You can ignore the time portion of a timestamp and only look at the date part, but this only works if you lock all your operations to UTC rather than local time.  In other words, treat `'2003-04-01'` as if it were `'2003-04-01T00:00:00.000Z'` and never convert it to local time or another time zone.

If you were using just the JavaScript `Date` object, then you would do:

```
const d = new Date('2003-04-01T00:00:00.000Z'); // the Z parses as UTC
const s = d.toISOString(); // this always emits UTC
```

But since you have a custom date format to parse and want to use day.js, you can do something like the following:

- Define a function to work around [day.js's parsing case sensitivity issue](https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs/issues/1720). (You need `Apr`, not `APR`.)

  ```
  const fixMonthName = (s) => s.replace(/[A-Z]{2}-/, (m) => m.toLowerCase());
  ```
- Parse the input string using [day.js's UTC mode](https://day.js.org/docs/parse/utc)

  ```
  const d = dayjs.utc(fixMonthName('01-APR-03'), 'DD-MMM-YY');
  ```
- Get the output as a string however you would like, using any of [day.js's display functions](https://day.js.org/docs/display/display):

  ```
  const s = d.toISOString();         // "2003-04-01T00:00:00.000Z"
  // or
  const s = d.format('YYYY-MM-DD');  // "2003-04-01"
  ```
- Note that if you need a JavaScript `Date` object, do not use `$d` but instead call [`.toDate()`](https://day.js.org/docs/display/as-javascript-date).  From there, make sure you are only using the UTC representation of the `Date` object.  Keep in mind that while some environments will emit UTC when logging a `Date` object to the console (as if you called `.toISOString()`, other environments will emit the local time equivalent (as if you called `.toString()`.

Comment: That is a fascinating explanation! I had no idea it was this complicated. Unfortunately, the result of the suggested code still has the same issue, and I am getting the date string one day prior to the original input date. I think the issue is that dayjs itself returns an incorrect date and already converts it to the incorrect time.

Comment: It shouldn't be off by a day if you are both parsing as UTC and formatting as UTC.  Perhaps you are calling some other function, or providing some other type of input?

Comment: I added the code I am now using to the question. I just copied and pasted from your comment.

Comment: As you can see, the issue is already with the variant d after the dayjs conversion.

Comment: Maybe you need the first two lines from the sample [in the docs](https://day.js.org/docs/en/plugin/utc)?  (I think you need to extend dayjs with both the `utc` and `customParseFormat` plugins.)

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't work either. Nothing works. It's like the localization isn't working at all, no matter what form I'm trying to use to change it.